# Personalized notifications in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create an application that displays a personalized notification on the notification bar of the phone, but I don't know how to add this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the basics on programmatically creating notifications, please refer to this Android documentation: [Notifications Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications)

In addition to that overview page, there are many more pages with further detail and code examples on the left pane.

Depending on the purpose of the notification and how/when you plan to generate one, doing so programmatically within your app's code might not be feasible for your use case as there are certain limitations. Therefore, you might use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging) to accomplish your use case because the service provides more flexibility.